# How do I use conditions in google forms, as I design a form to collect subcategory data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Can I use google form to collect multiple answers about an individual or group of individuals.

If the question is : How many people will participate?
And the answer to this is **5 or 6 or 7**, (I do not have control over what the answer will be) then google forms will create another set of fields to enter more details about the say **5**  people like;

**Name:.......... Age:.........

Sex:............   email:.........

Phone number ........**

I will then be able to collect all the above details for each person mentioned

Comment: Welcome. Question should include a brief description of what were searched/researched about this. Reference [ask].

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question.  Stack Overflow is not for how to make the settings in a Google Form.

Comment: @SandyGood is correct, but the closest we could advice is to check the [`createChoice(value, navigationItem)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue-navigationitem). This function will let you go to a page when the user select a specific choice. **Note** that you have to set this manually and there is no feature that this can be dynamic. The rest will depend on your implementation. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sandy Good I was asking from a programming perspective if amendments can be made on the code to accommodate this requirement

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, thanks, I am going to check this out